# JSF + HashMap and its key

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, key, hashmap, session-bean

I have a database with 2 tables `CD` and `Song`. Session bean access then entity classes of those two tables. In my backing bean, I just have a `String cd` and `HashMap<CDName, CDName> cds` that will hold the list of CD return back from my sessionbean, so in JSF I would do something like this.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="cd" value="#{backingBean.cd}">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select CD" itemValue="" />
     <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.cds}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

This successfully load a list of cd onto the drop down list, and if I select a cd, `cd` variables would hold the name of the CD I select. This work great if `CDName` is unique. But unfortunately it is not. So what I want is `HashMap<ID, CDName> cds` where `ID` is the PK in table `CD`. But now how I can set it up, so when I click on a item from the CD drop down list, I get the `ID` back in my backingbean, so that I can do something like this, in my session bean

```
CD cd = EntityManager.find(CD.class, the id that I get back from JSF page)
```

essentially I want to obtain the `cd` object that I just click on, keep it in mind, there might be duplication. If my design is bad, please point out. Help please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be set in the property behind `#{backingBean.cd}` as illustrated in your code example.

So, basically:

```
CD cd = em.find(CD.class, this.cd);
```

Alternatively, you can also have a `HashMap<CD, CDName>` instead and use a `javax.faces.convert.Converter` which does basically the following:

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    return em.find(CD.class, value);
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    return String.valueOf(((CD) value).getId());
}
```

#### See also:

- [Objects in `h:selectOneMenu`.](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html)

---

That said, a `HashMap` is by nature **unordered**. Are you sure you don't rather need a `TreeMap` (automatic sort by key) or a `LinkedHashMap` (insertion order)?

Comment: In your `Backing Map`, can u just not return `Map<String, Object>` directly to the JSF, or do you have to convert it into `List<SelectItem>` like what you did?

Comment: Not directly, the key-value pair should be swapped to get it displayed as you want. I.e. `Map<Object, String>`. The `Map` key will namely become option value and the `Map` value will become the option label.

Comment: shouldn't `EntityManager` be lower-case? :)

Comment: Yes, it should be a variable :)